# Visual Studio ClickOnce Deployment with Administrator rights

Tags: c#, deployment, clickonce

Our C# application uses ClickOnce for deployment. Everything works like a charm despite the fact, that the application needs administrator privileges at some point. ClickOnce seemingly does not support requirement of elevated rights. 
We tried setting the level to "Administrator" in the app's manifest file and also restarted the application after startup with the "runas" verb but both approaches won't work for our case, because the user should **not** be forced to manually run the app as Administrator (the UAC dialog that pops up asking for permission of elevated rights). 
Is there any workaround to this?

The elevated rights are needed to start a WebApp on localhost.

**EDIT**
Our Code to restart with admin rights:

```
 try
        {
            this.webApp = WebApp.Start(url: baseAddress, startup: Startup);
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            MessageBoxButtons buttons = MessageBoxButtons.RetryCancel;
            DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Dummy app could not start a Web Server on Localhost.\nPlease make sure that no other instance of Dummy app is currently runnning and try again.", "Dummy app has encountered an error", buttons);
            if (result == DialogResult.Retry) {
                var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("Dummy_app.exe") { Verb = "runas" };
                Process.Start(startInfo);
                Environment.Exit(0); 
            } else
            {
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Is it asking for elevated privileges during install, or when you try to run the app after install?

Comment: At the moment it asks because we made it to, at app start. The logic is, we try to start the web app, and if that fails we restart the application with administrator rights. That causes the UAC dialog to pop up, which we do not want